# PHP validate float via IS_FLOAT

Tags: php, validation

I need to validate inputs - find out, if inputs are float. According to websites, my code should work, but it doesnt.

```
<?php
$new_estimate=array("3.3","10.3","1.1","2.35");
$mistake="no";

for ($i=0; $i<(sizeof($new_estimate)); $i++)
    {
       if (!is_float($new_estimate[$i]))
         {
         $mistake="yes";
         }
    }

echo $mistake;
?>
```

I think all values of array are float, but browser shows "yes" - instead my expectation. I dont understand, why it doesnt work.

Comment: Those are strings not floats. `$new_estimate=array(3.3,10.3,1.1,2.35);` A `var_dump()` would show you this.

Comment: Remove the quotes 'round yer floats

Comment: Looking for [`FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT`](http://php.net/filter_var) perhaps, when the sample array is meant to be form input?

Comment: you can update existing code like this if (!is_float((float) $new_estimate[$i]))

Comment: @saqibahmad If you cast to `float`, it's bound to be a `float` so testing for that will not do much...

Answer (score 2):

It is because [is_float()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-float.php) checks if the type of a variable is float, and you are working with an array of string values. To validate inputs you can use [filter_var()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) as in example below.

```
$new_estimate = array( "3.3", "10.3", "1.1", "2.35" );

$mistake = (bool) array_filter( $new_estimate, function( $item ) {
    return !filter_var( $item, FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This are strings in your array, if you'd like them to be floats remove the `"` around the numbers. If you intend to check for numbers instead of the concrete type, use `is_numeric` ([Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php)).

```
$new_estimate = array(3.3, 10.3, 1.1, 2.35);
```

Furthermore, instead using the strings `"yes"` and `"no"` for `$mistake`, set them `true` or `false` and use the variable as a boolean.